# Is there a server-less option for capturing ApplePay payments?

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, applepay

I successfully setup ApplePay in my iOS application but I could not connect to a payment provider (like Stripe) because they all require a server of some kind to process the payments.  My app runs completely server-less via the Firebase Firestore and Google storage back-end services.

Question - is there a payment provider that connects with ApplePay without the need for a server?

I've setup PayPal and they offer a completely server-less option, I assume there has to be at least one provider doing this?

I don't have the expertise or money to create & run the server in question.

Comment: You need a server.  There are secrets involved that cannot be stored securely in an app.  You could look at Google Cloud Run or Firebase functions

Answer (score 2):

You will need a server to integrate Apple Pay directly into your iOS app. That said, a workaround would be to use a no-code solution like [Payment Links](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links) within a WebView. That said, this will not scale particularly well and you will have a hard time handling fulfillment without a server and [Webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks).